# Writing data to iBeacon

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have a hardware,which is acts as iBeacon , and i have programmed it to also be writeable .

I know how you write data to characteristic a BLE module with :

```
[self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:self.discoveredCharacteristic
                      type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

But an i beacon returns `CLBeacon` :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
```

I am looking for a way to connect to the iBeacon and write data to it, thats because i know the hardware was programmed by me, to be able to connect and receive data(as an iBeacon)

Comment: You will have to connect to as a normal Bluetooth device, since the iBeacon library provided by Apple is read only.

Comment: thanks, i saw you can write data to its major and minor, is that correct?  [beacon setValue @"FAVC" for Key:@"Major"]

Comment: No.  You can set a major and minor to look for in your beacon region, but these values need to be set in the beacon through some other method (typically Core Bluetooth/GATT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hardware was programmed by you, then you should know how it accepts written values. Does is use GATT characteristics to do so?  If so, look at `CoreBluetooth` APIs in iOS to do this.  Properties of `CLBeacon` are read only, so you cannot use them.

Comment: you right i can't do that, but even so , i was trying to switch to BLE when iBeacon detected ,than to write to it with BLE, and it seems that the system is "occupied" with the iBeacon and i can't SWITCH to BLE. if i start over and only do BLE, it works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105765/moving-from-ibeacon-to-ble-in-real-time