# Switching from iBeacon to BLE in real time?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Our beacon hardware was programmed to be iBeacon + writeable BLE .
So i can discover it with iBeacon , and also connect to it via BLE.

I would like to scan for iBeacon, and when i enter the region (app is in background) , and the delegate is being called, he will than switch to BLE and connect to the device with BLE :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    // here connect as usual via bluetooth
}
```

So,as i said, i can separately write/discover the hardware, but when i am trying to connect to the module, from the delegate via BLE ( when app in background,i enter the region,delegate is ON, than in background trying to connect with BLE,
its not working, although i can in background do other things when inside a region, for example, connect to a server .)

Is there anything i can do to make it happen? i was also trying to stop the beacon region monitoring, but even so, he can't connect to the BLE from background .

Comment: do you have the background mode key set in the info.plist

Comment: yes,all of them. seems like the problem is that the app awakes for 10 seconds only and the BLE does not have enough time to connect.. can you get more time from the system ?

Answer (score 1):

to do stuff in bg you need to request time from the os. you then get an identifier.

```
//identifier
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier;
```

request it by calling:

```
if(!self.backgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"expired, fail, throw!!!");
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"BeaconServiceKilled" reason:@"Expired in bg" userInfo:nil];
    }];
}
```

when done then release it

```
if(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't understand how to use it.. where this code goes to, and where i connect to the BLE ?

Comment: the property goes into the interface  and the request when you start BLE connection. The finish when you are done with everything... maybe when you leave the region?

Comment: thank you very much , a few things, first, do i put the BLE connection before the block you wrote, or inside it ? second, is this allowed by Apple? is this require some user permissions? how much time can you get? seems strange that apple allows that because i can keep it do stuff forever..

Comment: Well, thanks it works, it gives you more time, BUT the BLE will not connect in background, only in foreground .. can't set it to do that..